# Creating Bins/groups in Excel

Tags: excel

**Background:**

I want to create bins/groups in Excel based on a column value,for example: if column "A" contains  values from second row till 501 row and each row contains different values(in float point decimal) in the same column (column A), then i want to define a range of values in column "B" as group1 to group5 (we can mark them as 1 ,2,3,4 and 5) , so that each group have 100 row values for column "B" as 1,2,3,4 or 5.

**My attempt:**

What i am trying is two way, first i sort the data into ascending order of column "A" then use the below formula to tabulate groups/bins.It works perfectly, but hangs when there is a big chunk of data.

```
 =INT((ROWS($A$1:A1) - 1) * 5 / ROWS($A$1:$A$501))+1
```

**My question:**

What i require is to calculate these bin values efficiently may be using formula like percentile, i also tried it but its giving me *one* value for a range (which is obvious).
The row count formula (present above) also doesn't quite seem to work if there are ties in the values present in "A", i.e.the same value can be on two different groups if present at the boundary of bins(groups).

I hope my problem is clear, thanks in advance and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all to calculate the number of bins you may want to try few rule of thumbs like `√n` or more robust method like `Freedman-Diaconis rule(Max -Min)/h where h=2∗IQR∗n−1/3.` However looking at your question you want to put the bin value to individual number best of some technique. Here is one way to do this

Compute `Min, 1st Quartile, 2nd Quartile, 3rd Quartile and 4th quartile` out of your dataset

Then assign bin value for them, as in Min =1, 1st Quartile =2 ......4th Quartile = 5

So I have main data (randomly generated number) in column B like this

```
VALUES
    0.406199302
    0.211390353
    0.680235687
    0.351327448
    0.327081614
    0.919550151
    0.103904963
    0.575393934
    0.867757642
    0.879022189
    0.663474053
    0.423916716
    0.433612145
    0.409092672
```

From Column D to F i have calculated these fields

```
MIN         0.0040863823    1
QUARTILE1   0.2362226262    2
QUARTILE2   0.4800558265    3
QUARTILE3   0.7491378854    4
QUARTILE4   0.9972357897    5
```

In column C where I am calculating bin I can use this formula `=IF(AND(B2>=$E$1,B2<$E$2),1,IF(AND(B2>=$E$2,B2<$E$3),2,IF(AND(B2>=$E$3,B2<$E$4),3,IF(AND(B2>=$E$4,B2<$E$5),4,5))))`

Which would result in

```
VALUES    BIN
0.406199302   2
0.211390353   1
0.680235687   3
0.351327448   2
0.327081614   2
0.919550151   4
0.103904963   1
```